# PrintScreen image capturing

Tags: java, awt, actionlistener, printscreen

I need to write a program that I will create a runnable jar and distribute. The functions should be like below:

when double click the jar, it will open a window.
it will ask the path where to save the image files.
it will then ask whether to add any prefix / suffix / both on every image along with timestamp for unique name.
it will also ask what image format to use.
the app can be minimized and closed
it will take a full screenshot whenever PrintScreen is pressed and save.
Please provide a programme that is complete. I have gathered pieces but could not put them in one. Here is my code :-

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainClass
{
static String location = "";
static String prefix = "";
static String format = "";
static Date timestamp = new Date();

public static void main(String args[])
{
    try 
    {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
JFrame f = new JFrame("Text Field Examples");
f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

final JTextField textField1 = new JTextField("Enter Location To Save Image Files");
textField1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        textField1.setText("");
    }
});
textField1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        location = textField1.getText();
        System.out.println(location);
    }
});
f.getContentPane().add(textField1);

final JTextField textField2 = new JTextField("Enter Prefix or Leave Empty");
textField2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        textField2.setText("");
    }
});
textField2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        prefix = textField2.getText();
        System.out.println(prefix);
    }
});
f.getContentPane().add(textField2);

String  jlistData[] =
    {
        "GIF",
        "PNG",
        "JPG"
    };
final JComboBox  jlist = new JComboBox<String>( jlistData );
jlist.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        format = jlist.getSelectedItem().toString();
        System.out.println(format);

    }
});
f.getContentPane().add(jlist);

f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
} 
catch (Exception evt) 
{
    evt.printStackTrace();
}



try
{
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);


    Transferable t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null);
    RenderedImage image = (RenderedImage) t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);

    ImageIO.write(image, format, new File(new String(location+prefix+image+timestamp)));
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}   

}
}
```

The first try catch block can open a window, take image format, prefix and storage location. The second try catch block alone can take screen shot when run not when printscreen key is pressed but with the first try catch it does not print anything. So, what to do to take the screenshot when printscreen key is pressed ?

Comment: The problem you have is it's impossible to capture key events at a global level from within Java without resorting to JNI/JNA intergration

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078646/jna-keyboard-hook-in-windows)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Do you need to do that when all you want is a full screen shot (as opposed to a *window* shot where you must place the cursor)?

Comment: If you want to detect when the print screen button is pressed while the application doesn't have keyboard focus, then yes, this is the only solution

Comment: Hi, I have developed a code that when clicked on button takes screenshot as i couldnot integrate PrintScreen with my code.

Answer (score 2):

I have approached the solution in a little bit another way.
As people always works with mouse while on online meeting, I removed the clause of PrintScreen button from keyboard and instead the attendees can click on swing window button to capture screen.

My solution as follows:

MainClass.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainClass{
static String location = "";
static String prefix = "";
static String format = "";

public static void main(String args[])
{
    try 
    {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    final JFrame f = new JFrame("ENTER ALL DETAILS BELOW");
    f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    final JTextField textField1 = new JTextField("Enter Location To Save Image Files");
    textField1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            textField1.setText("");
        }
    });
    f.getContentPane().add(textField1);

    final JTextField textField2 = new JTextField("Enter MeetingID");
    textField2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            textField2.setText("");
        }
    });
    f.getContentPane().add(textField2);

    String  jlistData[] =
        {
            "GIF",
            "PNG",
            "JPG"
        };
    final JComboBox  jlist = new JComboBox<String>( jlistData );
    f.getContentPane().add(jlist);

    final JButton jButton = new JButton("OKAY");
    jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            location = textField1.getText();
            prefix = textField2.getText();
            format = jlist.getSelectedItem().toString();
            System.out.println(location);
            System.out.println(prefix);
            System.out.println(format);
            f.setVisible(false);
            PrintButton.printButton();
        }
    });
    f.getContentPane().add(jButton);

    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    } 
    catch (Exception evt) 
    {
        evt.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

PrintButton.java

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;


public class PrintButton 
{
    static void printButton()
    {
        try 
    {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    //final JFrame f = new JFrame("Print Screen App");
    Dlg f = new Dlg(new JFrame(), "PRINT");
    f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    final JButton jButton = new JButton("OKAY");
    jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            PrintScreen.printScreen();
        }
    });
    f.getContentPane().add(jButton);

    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    } 
    catch (Exception evt) 
    {
        evt.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

class Dlg extends JDialog {
    public Dlg(JFrame frame, String str) {
    super(frame, str);
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}
}
```

PrintScreen.java

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class PrintScreen 
{
static void printScreen()
{
    try
    {
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);

        Transferable t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null);
        RenderedImage image = (RenderedImage) t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);

        ImageIO.write(image, MainClass.format, new File(new String(MainClass.location+ "\\" +MainClass.prefix+"_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"."+MainClass.format)));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

I hope this will be helpfull to some freinds. Is there any scope to improve this?

How to create a installable version for Windows and Linux/Ubuntu and Linux/RedHat ?